# Did anyone try using "Call Virtual User Generator Script" from toolbox for API testing?

Tags: hp-uft, vugen

For testing one my functionality I want to call VUGEN script in my APItest in UFT. I added the "Call Virtual User Generator Script" from toolbox to my test. But I am unable to give the script path. In the screenshot attached [calling vugen script from UFT error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqx8p.jpg), when I am trying to locate the error to give the path of my vugen script I am not even getting the popup to select the path. Did anyone try this option or is there any known issue with UFT for calling vugen script.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do NOT have VUGen installed on my system. But in order to update the script path, you need to update in Properties section of that activity.

To view the Property section, click:

```
View -> Properties
```

Now from here click on the highlighted button and it will give you the script selection window.

[image]

Comment: Awesome !!! Thank you so much :) :) :)  I did not realize that I need to click that icon until you highlighted it. I am able to add the script path.

Comment: I have another question, I added script path and ran it. But its giving me error message Mdrv Error. Error: Vuser type "JavaHTTTP" specified in C:/test.usr cannot be found (or its section is empty) in C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Analysis\dat\mdrv.dat. [MsgId: MERR-10770]. After some research I found that I need to add new Vuser type JAvaHTTP in mdrv.dat file. Do you know how to add the new vuser type? I found this link on how to add new vuser type. http://claudihome.com/html/LR/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/166150_t_mult_creat_new_vuser_type.htm but not sure what all values need to given.

Comment: Glad to help and I wish I can help more, but as stated I've personally not worked on this part so, I won't be of any help. But [**`here`**](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/100050_c_vugen_overview.htm) is the link to documentation which might help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it today

Comment: I was able to successfully add the JavaHTTP Vuser type. Thank you

Comment: Glad that you figured it out.